# pandas data-frame from .csv file into single cell

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, keras

I have video files in three directories (Train , Development , Test ) and

there is two .csv files ( the features are in one  .csv file , but the labels

and file names are  in other .csv file ). I'm trying to make a dataframe by

selecting some colunms from the two .csv files to feed it to keras CNN model .

Below is what I tried to read some features from the 1st  .csv file , but I

don't know if this this is the right way to do it ?

```
import io
import numpy as np
def read_data(file_path):

data = pd.read_csv(file_path,sep=',')
data =data.iloc[0:1560, [0,680,681,682,683,684]] 
return data

df=read_data('dev_001.csv')
print(df.shape)
df.head()

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

[output features saved in data_frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrqNI.png)

I want now to insert this data frame into one cell so I have something like this :

Table :

```
Features                                          Subject_id           labels   

Extracted features from .csv file (data_frame )   ID from .csv file   Label from .csv file
```

Where I need  all features in .csv file in first cell. How this can be done ?

I tried this :

```
 new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Features': [temp_data_frame]})

 print(temp_data_frame.shape)

 print(new_df.shape)
(1560, 35)
(1, 1)
```

But it only takes the first row from (temp_data_frame)

Comment: i suggest printing out df.columns .. maybe there is a space in the timestamp column name you can't see.

Comment: I solved it using     data = pd.read_csv(file_path,sep=',',usecols=(0,2))  , but now I have problem with the labels that is in another .csv file , how can I read these cols with the labels from other .csv and make them as [features,labels] for each sample ?

Comment: just read two pandas dataframes and concatenate it, then zip the features with labels

Comment: print(new_df) is just showing first row  of temp_data_frame